# Html file is not working on php directory script website

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess

I have php web directory. I am trying to create sub folder with html template in it, but the issue is the server is showing following error"`Apache Server at www.mydomain.com Port 80`".

I have default empty .htaccess file.

This is the path where I have uploaded my html file.

http://www.mddir.com/movie/top-indian-movies/

Please help me to make this html file live.

Comment: "showing following error..." - but that isn't an error? You've tagged your question `.htaccess` - do you have an `.htaccess` file? Please add this to your question. "This is how the folder structure looks" - how does your folder structure look??

Comment: Yes. I have default empty .htaccess file. This is the path where I have uploaded my html file. http://www.mddir.com/movie/top-indian-movies/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> showing following error: "Apache Server at www.mydomain.com Port 80".

That is not an error, that is simply the directory listing when accessing the directory and the directory index document is not available.

It would seem you don't have a directory index enabled (or it's not set for `index.html`).

And I'm guessing you don't want to see a directory listing either.

Try adding the following to your `.htaccess` file:

```
# Disable directory listings
Options -Indexes

# Load index.html when requesting the bare directory
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

Comment: Awesome @user82217 . :). It is working. You saved my lot of time. Thank a ton for your quick response.